# Need to remove word with certain separating character in list using python

Tags: python, list

Need to remove the word separating characters (such as `, . - * !` and *space*) from each of the word, present in list words.
Store the obtained result again in the list words.

I can't seem to remove the whole word in my words list. Is there such a thing? I tried below code but it wont remove the words with above chars. Also, can I need to use list comprehension and strip func.

```
words=([s.strip(",.-*! ") for s in (Convert(setofStrings))])
print(words)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: The question is unclear. In the title you say "Need to remove word" and in the text "Need to remove the word separating characters". Please clarify.

Comment: sorry i meant the chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip()` will only remove those characters from beginning or end of string. You need to either use [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.translate)  or for more complicated regular expression based substitution [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub).

Example of `translate()` using `deletechars` argument:

```py
words = ['-foo.,', '!b*a-!r', 'ba*!,-z']
words = [s.translate(None, '-.!*,') for s in words]
```

and example of `re.sub()`:

```py
import re

words = ['-foo.,', '!b*a-!r', 'ba*!,-z']
words = [re.sub(r'[-\.!\*,]', '', s) for s in words]
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: sorry, i meant remove only the chars mentioned

Comment: Updated my answer with examples. Also your question is not very clear. Title says you want to remove word but your code snippet convinces that you just have trouble removing characters from words in list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
b = ["aa-2", "bb-2"]
words = [x.split("-") for x in b]
```

output:

```
[['aa', '2'], ['bb', '2']]
```

That is if you want to split the words, if you just want to remove the characters you can use `.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you could use `re.sub` in combination with a list comprehension if your aim is to remove the characters from a list of strings.

```
import re
list_of_words = ['test.','cool!','wow ','y*,!']
result = [re.sub('[,\.\-\*\! ]', '', word) for word in list_of_words]
```